# Colocar um IF com varias condições

Tags: php, if

Quero colocar um If com varias condições.

```
if ($row[??] != '' or NULL or 0000-00-00 )
```

Actualmente tenho assim mas quero colocar mais dois Row. tenho de criar mais if ou consigo acrescentar nesse If?

Comment: Tem mesmo de colocar uma condição `x != y` para cada `or`

Comment: Sobre as respostas abaixo, apenas cuidado com a precedência dos operadores. Há diferenças entre `and, or` e `&&, ||`    Veja teste no manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#117390

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema do seu `if` é que os `or` estão comparando nada com nada.

Você precisa comparar novamente com alguma coisa (`$row[??]` no seu caso):

```
if ($row['xpto'] != '' and $row['xpto'] != NULL and $row['xpto'] != '0000-00-00' )
```

Melhorando seu código, para verificar se a variável é vazia (`''` ou `NULL`), utilize a função [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php).

```
if (!empty($row['xpto']) and $row['xpto'] != '0000-00-00' )
```

**PS.:** Não esqueça as aspas na data! (`'0000-00-00'`)

**PS2.:** Analisando melhor, como você está verificando o que é **diferente**, logo o operador correto a se utilizar é o `and` (ou `&&`)

Comment: Ele quer diferente de vazio então deve usar !empty

Comment: Obg. corrigido.